# Neo4j : Why use UNWIND & Merge in @Query and get failed？

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

When I use neo4j, I think I have a tough problem.
The version of SDN is 6.3.0
And now, I have a column node and a table node：

```
@Data
@Node("Column")
public class ColumnNode {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Property
private String sourceName;

@Property
private String schemaName;

@Property
private String tableName;

@Property
private String name;

@Relationship(type = "BLOOD", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
private ColumnRelation columnRelation;
}
```

//---------------

```
@Data
@Node("Table")
public class TableNode {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Property
private String sourceName;

@Property
private String schemaName;

@Property
private String name;

@Property
private String tableComment;

@Relationship(type = "RELEVANCE", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
private TableRelation tableRelation;

@Relationship(type = "BELONG", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
private List<TableAndColumnRelation> tableAndColumnRelation;
}
```

Then I began to write my query. I want to associate multiple column nodes to table nodes at one time

```
@Query(value =
        "UNWIND :#{#froms} AS col " +
        "MERGE (c:Column { sourceName : col.sourceName, " +
                "schemaName : col.schemaName, " +
                "tableName : col.tableName, " +
                "name : col.name }) " +
        "MERGE (t:Table {sourceName : :#{#to.sourceName}, " +
                "schemaName : :#{#to.schemaName}, " +
                "name : :#{#to.name} }) " +
                "MERGE (c) -[r:BELONG]-> (t) ")
void mergeTableAndColumnRelations(@Param("froms") List<ColumnNode> froms, @Param("to") TableNode to);
```

However, things are not as I thought. There is an error in the code. Here is the error stack

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'name': (:Column {name: null})
```

The following is the printed stack information：

```
UNWIND $__SpEL__0 AS col MERGE (c:Column { sourceName : col.sourceName, schemaName : 
col.schemaName, tableName : col.tableName, name : col.name }) MERGE (t:Table {sourceName : 
$__SpEL__1, schemaName : $__SpEL__2, name : $__SpEL__3 }) MERGE (c) -[r:BELONG]-> (t) 
2022-08-04 19:23:20.041 TRACE 4076 --- [nio-8005-exec-1] org.springframework.data.neo4j.cypher    
: with parameters:
:param 0 => [{__labels__: ["Column"], __id__: null, __properties__: {name: "h", sourceName: 
"B", schemaName: "B", tableName: "B"}}]
:param 1 => {__labels__: ["Table"], __id__: null, __properties__: {name: "B", tableComment: 
null, sourceName: "B", schemaName: "B"}}
:param __SpEL__1 => "B"
:param __SpEL__0 => [{__labels__: ["Column"], __id__: null, __properties__: {name: "h", 
sourceName: "B", schemaName: "B", tableName: "B"}}]
:param __SpEL__3 => "B"
:param __SpEL__2 => "B"
:param froms => [{__labels__: ["Column"], __id__: null, __properties__: {name: "h", 
sourceName: "B", schemaName: "B", tableName: "B"}}]
:param to => {__labels__: ["Table"], __id__: null, __properties__: {name: "B", tableComment: 
null, sourceName: "B", schemaName: "B"}}
```

Thank you for browsing. How can I modify this code correctly, or is there a better way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j does not allow assigning a null value for an attribute/property. If it is null, neo4j will just skip assigning value to that property. Check first your data model to see if name is required to have a value or can be null/blank. There are two possible options to handle your issue on the error.

```
 Cannot merge due to null value 'name': (:Column {name: null})
```

1. If name is a mandatory field then you can filter invalid data in your query using WITH/WHERE clause

   ```
   UNWIND $froms AS col
   WITH col WHERE col.name IS NOT NULL
   MERGE (c:Column {name: col.name})
   ```
2. If name is NOT mandatory, then use the SET command such as below

   ```
   UNWIND $froms AS col
   MERGE (c:Column {sourceName: col.sourceName})
   SET c.name = col.name
   ```

In this way, neo4j will ignore the null value of name.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, which is very helpful to me. I did not describe the problem clearly, which was my mistake. I described it more clearly when I asked the author on GitHub. [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2579) 2579 Thank you again.